Prove: every strongly connected graph has at most one stationary distribution without manipulating with eigenvector
In mcs.pdf, Problem 21.12 says:

A digraph is strongly connected iff there is a directed path between every pair of
distinct vertices. In this problem we consider a finite random walk graph that is
strongly connected.
(a) Let $d_1$ and $d_2$ be distinct distributions for the graph, and define the maximum
dilation $\gamma$  of $d_1$ over $d_2$ to be
$$
\gamma::=\max_{x\in V}\frac{d_1(x)}{d_2(x)}
$$
Call a vertex x dilated if $d_1(x)=d_2(x)=\gamma$. Show that there is an edge $\langle y\to z\rangle$
from an undilated vertex y to a dilated vertex z. Hint: Choose any dilated vertex x
and consider the set D of dilated vertices connected to x by a directed path (going
to x) that only uses dilated vertices. Explain why $D\neq V$ , and then use the fact
that the graph is strongly connected.
(b) Prove that the graph has at most one stationary distribution. (There always is
a stationary distribution, but we’re not asking you prove this.) Hint: Let $d_1$ be a
stationary distribution and $d_2$ be a different distribution. Let z be the vertex from
part (a). Show that starting from $d_2$, the probability of z changes at the next step.
That is, $\hat{d_2}(z) \neq d_2(z)$.

stationary distribution definition (Here $\text{Rank}(x)$ means probability)

Definition 21.2.1. An assignment of probabilities to vertices in a digraph is a stationary distribution if for all vertices x
$$
\Pr[\text{at x}]  = \Pr[\text{go to x at next step}]
$$
Sergey and Larry defined their page ranks to be a stationary distribution. They
did this by solving the following system of linear equations: find a nonnegative number $\text{Rank}(x)$ for each vertex x such that
$$
\text{Rank}(x)=\sum_{\text{edges }\langle y\to x\rangle}\frac{\text{Rank}(y)}{\text{outdeg}(y)}\tag{21.15}
$$

This has one similar QA answer. But I want the solution following the hint above without manipulating with eigenvector probably.
I can understand (a). But for (b) it seems that (a) only gives the relation between probabilities of these 2 distributions without giving the infos about transition matrices (i.e. out degree) in these 2 distributions. Then how to show $\hat{d_2}(z) \neq d_2(z)$ without manipulating with eigenvector?
